# Not able to autowire JpaRepository in DAO

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am currently integrating JPA into my project that I previously used `HibernateTemplate`.

I did the following to configure it:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("package1, package2")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JpaConfiguration {


    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(){

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

        vendorAdapter.getJpaDialect();

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("package1, package2");
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory.getObject();
    }
```

Below is the class I am trying to call the repository from but I get an error when I hover over the call saying: `no-static field applicantEntryRepository cannot be referenced from a static context`.

```
public static PsHeldSkillEntry retrievePsHeldSkillEntry(SkillEntry primaryKey) throws DataAccessException {
    //HibernateTemplate ht = new HibernateTemplate(ComponentBuilder.getSessionFactory());

    //SkillEntry skill = ht.get(SkillEntry.class, primaryKey);

    SkillEntry skill = applicantEntryRepository.getOne(primaryKey);

    return skill;
}


}
```

`applicantEntryRepository` is autowired at the top of the class like so:

```
@Controller
public class ApplicantEntryDAO {

    @Autowired
    ApplicantEntryRepository applicantEntryRepository;
```

Repository

```
public interface ApplicantEntryRepository extends JpaRepository<SkillEntry,Long> {


}
```

Enitiy:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "HELD_SKILL")
@IdClass(SkillEntryPK.class)
public class SkillEntry
{
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is on autowiring or spring is just java problem, your calling `applicantEntryRepository` which is not static inside a static method, you ll have to make this variable static first

```
@Controller
public class ApplicantEntryDAO {

@Autowired
static ApplicantEntryRepository applicantEntryRepository;
```